# Strained my neck and feeling pain

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, muscle-soreness

Last week, I was trying to do some exercise lifting weight up. Suddenly I got a strain in my neck. I can move my neck but feel pain when doing so. I didn't do any exercises after that day, and I'm still getting the pain.

Please help me. How can I resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can you further explain what exercise you were doing? Just saying that you have a pain in your neck isn't useful. The more details you have to add to your question, the better.

Comment: I would probably see a doctor for this one.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of things which would cause such a response:

- Too much load too fast
- Insufficient food/potassium
- Insufficient hydration (not enough water)
- Bad technique

These are all common causes of muscle spasms.  If you are new to exercise, the muscle spasms can be more frequent than you may like.  Here are some ways to help prevent it from happening in the future:

- Have someone who is experienced make sure you are performing the exercise correctly
- Only increase weights 5-10 lbs at a time (2.5-5 kg)
- Make sure you aren't exercising on an empty stomach
- Make sure you get plenty of water during the day--and while you are exercising